# $ symbol in .class files

Tags: java, class

I have a program called `MyProgram.java`. I want to run it from different directory which will be run on another machine. So I made a directory and copied `MyProgram.class` file and made a `.bat` file that runs it (`Run.bat`) which includes the command: `@java MyProgram`.

This didn't work, I had to copy `SPVerification$1.class` that was generated from `Eclipse` in order to make it work.

What is this `XXX$1.class` files and why do I need them beside the `XXX.class` file in order to run an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are anonymous inner classes. In other words, when you have a piece like

```
class OuterClass {
    // ...
    void method() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            // ... code implementing Runnable interface ... 
        });
        // ... code to use t or whatever
    }
}
```

That generates anonymous inner class, in this case implementing the `Runnable` interface, and compiled code of that class goes to a `OuterClass$<number>.class` file. You can have more than one such class, with increasing number in the .class file name.

Note that syntax is exactly the same even if you extend a class with the anonymous inner class, instead of implementing an interface. This is a slightly different from creating named classes, where you need to use `implements` and `extends` as appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

If your .java file have inner/nested classes , post compilation those are generated as Yourclass$xxx.class files by the java compiler.

> Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class
>   files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as
>   MyClass$MyInnerClass.class. - [**Source**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

**Example**  (*edit*)

Considering following `Class` definition

```
// MyClass class
public class MyClass{

    // Inner class Test1
    class Inner1 {
    }

    // Inner class Test2
    class Inner2{
    }


    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Anonymous inner class 1
        new Object() {
        };

        // Anonymous inner class 2
        new Object() {
        };

        System.out.println("Bunch of $ files :)");
    }
}
```

Will generate these following Files

```
MyClass.class
MyClass$Inner1.class
MyClass$Inner2.class
MyClass$1.class
MyClass$2.class
```

Comment: Specifically XXX$1 is an *anonymous inner class*